# hibernate - select/load only field

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to add a field in a Hibernate table-mapped/entity class.

I want this field to not be mapped to an actual table column, and I want Hibernate not to try to insert/update it to the DB.

But I want to be able to load this field via a custom select in the DAO e.g. via

`query.addEntity(getPersistentClass().getName());`

The closest I got to this was by making the field `@Transient`,
but then even the select does not load its value. So this is not
quite what I need.

Is this possible at all and if so how?

Comment: AFAIK transient is the only way to not have a column be mapped using the ORM model.  If a field is not mapped to the database, then how could Hibernate possibly assign a value to it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My idea was to do an SQL query e.g. `select t.*, 1 as Disabled from table t` Then all the other fields come from the table and that `Disabled` field which I am talking about is loaded from the `Disabled` column of the record set that's returned by this query.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Where would the value of that field come from? Is it in the database or the result of some formula?

Comment: @Thomas OK, I've just given an example in my comment.

Comment: The closest thing which might fit your need would be to do a raw SQL query.  You are attempting to bypass the Hibernate framework, in this case why not just do a raw query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am doing a raw query `org.hibernate.SQLQuery`, I just want Hibernate to populate the results into my entity object so that I don't loop through an `Object[]`, hardcode column names and all that.

Comment: So you want all selected entities to have a flag `disabled = true`? An easy way would be to just iterate over the resultset and set it. An alternative might be a Hibernate formula (I don't have much experience with those though) or maybe a custom user type (although I don't know whether that can access the query parameter). It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve in the end, could you elaborate (e.g. the relevant parts of the entity and what you'd use that for)?

Comment: @peter.petrov No...you should either use the framework or not use it, but not something in between.

Comment: @Thomas What is not clear? I have an entity with say 3 fields which are mapped to the DB, and I want 1 field which is not mapped, but which can be loaded properly via `SELECT` of the above kind. `Disabled` will not be `true` for all entities, this was just an illustration. But yes, I want to enhance the entities with that `Disabled` field without this field having any mapping to a physical column.

Comment: So just to clarify: you want to define the value of the flag in the query? I'm not sure that is possible (maybe with a custom user type). But the question remains: why don't you set that flag _after_ loading the entities (or maybe have the entities do a lookup in their constructor, e.g. from a thread local - which I'd not prefer though)?

Comment: @Thomas Because I don't know how :) That's why I posted this question :) Show me some ideas, if you know how. Otherwise... I have another idea which I think to follow for now (until a good answer comes up here).

Comment: That's the problem: I don't know how you want to use that so I can't provide any examples. You only state _what_ you want but not _why_ (what's the goal you want to achieve)? As an example, if you'd do something like `List<MyEntity> list = query.getResultList();` I'd then just do a for-loop on that list and set the flag to whatever value is required.

Answer (score 1):

Well if i understand what you are trying to do well then i think the solution like this

@Column(name = "{name of column}", updatable = false)

In this way the hibernate will not try to update this column once the object created

Comment: I know about this `updatable` thing but my problem is that I don't have a column to map this field to. So I don't want it to be mapped to a physical table column at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then do it using transient, if you want to have this value from another table u can use formula for that

Comment: I didn't know this is possible. OK, I will do some research in that direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your getter must be a bit smarter.
For exemple you can the HibernateCallback interface from spring like that:

```
public String getName(Session session) {
 return new HibernateCallback<String>() {
  @Override
  public String doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
   return session.createSQLQuery("SELECT NAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SOME_CONDITIONS").uniqueResult();
  }
 }.doInHibernate(session);
}
```

A better way would be to create a kind of execute method in another class where you have access to the session.
With that solution you can still mark your field as `@Transient`.

Comment: Thanks but if I load 100 entities wouldn't that trigger 100 separate queries to the DB? If so, I don't want that.

Comment: It will call the DB only when it will be asked to. But and the end of the day yes if you want to retrieve the information for 100 different entities it will to go 100 times to the DB. Maybe you can think of way to use that to retrieve all the entities name with a single round trip to the DB. Then map the result to the right entity.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to find out, how to do it with 1 round-trip to the DB.

Comment: You can also go plain jdbc to the database just to retrieve the name and the id for all the entity you previously loaded. Then you can map the result to each entity using the id.

Comment: @peter.petrov something like 'session.createSQLQuery("SELECT NAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SOME_CONDITIONS").addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG).addScalar("NAME", Hibernate.STRING);' This will return an Object arrays. You can see: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
@Column(name = "{name of column}", insertable=false, updatable = false)

Do not mark the field as @Transient.

This way this property will not be inserted or updated but can be used in selects.